# Position absolute within a position fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a "hamburger" menu that is fixed over the entire page.
If the "hamburger" is clicked a menu slides open from the left till 50% of the width of the page.

The "hamburger" icon slides to the right with the menu. I want the icon to slide to the absolute right of the page.

Since the page can have different widths (100%) I can't set a `width` in px.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a#click-a').click(function() {
    $('.hoofdmenu').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });

});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 300px;
}
.hoofdmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.nav-view {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.nav-view div.hamburger {
  left: 330px;
}
.hoofdmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hoofdmenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hoofdmenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoofdmenu">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <a href="#" id="click-a">
      <img width="80" height="80" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/220px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" style="color:#FFF;">Link</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: " error that JQuery is not defined..." - on the left of jsFiddle screen you need to add link to jQuery as "External resources"

Comment: Oh wow. Thnx guys for the JSFiddle fix. Now the problem is clear for u :)

Comment: What? You mean problem's gone? Or we can see the problem in the demo code? I've moved your example code inline so we can see it without jumping to a different site

Comment: No the problem remains. The Jquery issue was a Fiddle problem (for me) I still need to have the hamburger aligned to the right if the menu is open!

Comment: i would prefer a fiddle

Comment: @Interactive Be careful with your words, there are two votes to close this post because you said, "it's working now"

Comment: it should be like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/cr2s1uuu/

Comment: @Pingbeat SO prefers inline examples, wanna play with it? Use the "Copy snippet to your answer" button

Comment: @Banzay. No the icon should be at the very right of the page, but dynamically because the page has different widths

Comment: there's nothing like selector `.nav-view div.hamburger` in HTML-code

Comment: @Banzay. The selector `.nav-view` is added if the icon is clicked. `div.hamburger` is already in the parent `div` so when the selector is added the `div.hamburger` excists

Comment: I respect all your answers and will take them into consideration the next time I post something but now I need a solution for my problem! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want but maybe the unit `vw` helps you

```
.nav-view div.hamburger {
  left: 85vw;
}
```

With this the Hamburger should be alignt to the right if the menu is opened.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a#click-a').click(function() {
    $('.hoofdmenu').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 300px;
}
.hoofdmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.nav-view {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.nav-view div.hamburger {
  left: 85vw;
}
.hoofdmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hoofdmenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hoofdmenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoofdmenu">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <a href="#" id="click-a">
      <img width="80" height="80" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/220px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" style="color:#FFF;">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. I use this for font-sizes but didn't know I could use this for width and heights!

Comment: Sure it is a screen size based unit so you can use it for that. So that solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah. Great it was a simple fix!